# Why later time series are missing when doing offset querying based on certain time period results in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I use the query for certain time period of Apache IoTDB to obtain the total number of time series, and then perform `offset` paging query according to this total number.

I found that there is a large amount of data missing in the results, and what may be the reason for this? I used aligned time series, and the version is 1.2.0, compiled locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the concept and see if you understand how to use `offset` statement in Apache IoTDB. For example, `limit 5 offset 3` means that the nearest 5 time series will be returned starting from the third time series. See if your reduction of data was because you reverse writing these two numbers for `limit` and `offset`.